# How do I get GLFW Vulkan surface creation working with mingw-w64

Tags: g++, glfw, vulkan, mingw-w64, msys2

### Problem

I'm trying to build and run a vulkan + glfw program with g++ on Windows. I installed gcc, glfw3, and vulkan using msys2's pacman.

When my program calls `glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface);` it returns with `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT`.

### What I did

Install msys2 and use pacman to install:

- mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw
- mingw-w64-x86_64-vulkan-headers
- mingw-w64-x86_64-vulkan-loader
- mingw-w64-x86_64-vulkan-validation-layers

Download [part 5 of the vulkan-tutorial.com tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/05_window_surface.cpp) and build it using:

`g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -g -c 05_window_surface.cpp -o main.o -lglfw3 -lvulkan`

`g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -g main.o -o main -lglfw3 -lvulkan`

Following the tutorial's setup for Visual Studio works flawlessly however I would prefer to use a different development enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into it more and finding this github issue: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1810, I have fixed my problem by changing my `-lvulkan` flag to `-L/path/to/VulkanSDK/1.2.176.1/Lib -l:vulkan-1.lib`